# JaCoCo XML reports not generated for code coverage

Tags: gradle, code-coverage, jacoco, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I currently have a gradle build script for a KMM multiplatform library that looks like below. I'm trying to use JaCoCo to report the test results and code coverage. I can see somewhere the test results in HTML, but I don't get to see the XML reports for test results and code coverage generated anywhere. How can I change this gradle file so that I can get the XML reports generated?
I'm using `./gradlew testCoverage`

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.10"
    id("com.android.library")
    id("kotlin-android-extensions")
    jacoco
}
group = "xxx"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

val coroutinesVersion = "1.3.9-native-mt"
val ktorVersion = "1.4.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    ios {
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {         
            dependencies {
                // ...
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization:$ktorVersion")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-android:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }

        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:$ktorVersion")
            }

            val targetName = System.getenv("TARGET_NAME") ?: ""

            if (targetName.endsWith("xxx")){
                kotlin.srcDirs("src/prod/kotlin")
            } else {
                kotlin.srcDirs("src/dev/kotlin")
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))

                api("io.ktor:ktor-client-mock:$ktorVersion")
                api("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutinesVersion")
            }
        }

        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.12")
            }
        }
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion(29)
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(29)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("environment")
    productFlavors {

        create("dev") {
            dimension = "environment"
        }

        create("prod") {
            dimension = "environment"
        }
    }
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5"
}

val jacocoTestReport by tasks.creating(JacocoReport::class.java) {
    reports {
        xml.isEnabled = true
        csv.isEnabled = false
        html.isEnabled = false
    }
}

val jacocoTestCoverageVerification by tasks.creating(JacocoCoverageVerification::class.java) {
    dependsOn(jacocoTestReport)
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = "0.8".toBigDecimal()
            }
        }
    }
}

val testCoverage by tasks.registering {
    group = "verification"
    description = "Runs the unit tests with coverage."

    dependsOn("test", jacocoTestReport, jacocoTestCoverageVerification)
    tasks["jacocoTestReport"].mustRunAfter("test")
    tasks["jacocoTestCoverageVerification"].mustRunAfter("jacocoTestReport")
}

val packForXcode by tasks.creating(Sync::class) {
    group = "build"
    val mode = System.getenv("CONFIGURATION")?.toUpperCase() ?: "DEBUG"
    val sdkName = System.getenv("SDK_NAME") ?: "iphonesimulator"
    val targetName = "ios" + if (sdkName.startsWith("iphoneos")) "Arm64" else "X64"
    val framework = kotlin.targets.getByName<KotlinNativeTarget>(targetName).binaries.getFramework(mode)
    inputs.property("mode", mode)
    dependsOn(framework.linkTask)
    val targetDir = File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
    from({ framework.outputDirectory })
    into(targetDir)
}
tasks.getByName("build").dependsOn(packForXcode)
```

PS.: I intentionally masked some strings in the code that are sensitive.

Comment: Found a related issue at the Gradle's GitHub: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9854

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and solved it by specifying the source directories and execution data. You might need to change these values according to your project.

```
    sourceDirectories.setFrom(files(project.projectDir))
    executionData.setFrom(
            fileTree(project.projectDir) {
                setIncludes(setOf("**/**/*.exec", "**/**/*.ec"))
            }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see the xml file on the report folder now!

Comment: where to add these ?